# Can I make a loop with the renderIndicator bullets of react responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a carousel component where I aim to show only 6 bullets as indicators. These indicators should seamlessly navigate through all the items in the carousel, looping back to the start when the end is reached.

Currently, I've attempted to limit the indicators, but the navigation continues beyond the specified 6 bullets without looping back to the beginning of the carousel items.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
<Carousel
                swipeScrollTolerance={100}
                preventMovementUntilSwipeScrollTolerance
                infiniteLoop={true}
                showArrows={true}
                showIndicators={isMobile}
                showStatus={!isMobile}
                showThumbs={!isMobile}
                width={'100%'}
                dynamicHeight={false}
                centerMode={false}
                emulateTouch={true}
                autoPlay={false}
                renderThumbs={() =>
                    images.map((src, index) => (<Image className="ga-product-thumbnails !pointer-events-auto" onLoadingComplete={(img) => onOptimizedImageLoaded(img, src)} key={`${carouselName}-thumbnails-${index}`} src={src} alt={"image"} height={450} width={550} />))
                }
                renderIndicator={(onClickHandler, isSelected, index, label, total) => {
                    const defStyle = { backgroundColor: "#d9d9d95e", cursor: "pointer" };
                    let style = { ...defStyle };
                    const indicatorsCount = 6; // Number of indicators to display
                    const itemsCount = total; // Total number of carousel items


                    const loopIndex = index % indicatorsCount;


                    const step = Math.floor(itemsCount / indicatorsCount);
                    if (index < indicatorsCount) {
                        style = isSelected ? { ...defStyle, backgroundColor: "#7e7e7e" } : { ...defStyle };

                        return (
                            <span
                                className={'product-carousel-bullet'}
                                style={style}
                                onClick={onClickHandler}
                                onKeyDown={onClickHandler}
                                value={loopIndex}
                                key={loopIndex}
                                role="button"
                                tabIndex={0}
                                aria-label={`${label} ${loopIndex + 1}`}
                            ></span>
                        );
                    }
                    return null;
                }}
                renderItem={(children) => children}
                onChange={(index) => setCurrentImage({image: images[index], index: index})}
                thumbWidth={86}
                onClickItem={() => setIsFullCarouselOpen(true)}
                selectedItem={currentImage.index}
                renderArrowNext={(clickHandler) => <CaretIconRight id="ga-product-sliderimagenes-right" className="ga-product-sliderimagenes w-[48px] h-[48px] xs:w-[48px] xs:h-[48px] text-[#4d4d4d] absolute top-[50%] right-0 cursor-pointer p-[10px] xs:mr-[-12px] mr-[-16px]" onClick={clickHandler} />}
                renderArrowPrev={(clickHandler) => <CaretIconLeft id="ga-product-sliderimagenes-left" className="ga-product-sliderimagenes w-[48px] h-[48px] xs:w-[48px] xs:h-[48px] text-[#4d4d4d] absolute top-[50%] left-0 z-10 cursor-pointer p-[10px] xs:ml-[-12px] ml-[-16px]" onClick={clickHandler} />}
            >

                {images.map((src, index) => (
                    <div key={`${carouselName}-carousel-images-${index}`}>
                        {useZoom && optimizedImages.hasOwnProperty(src) && <MagnifierPreview
                            className={"xs:hidden"}
                            imageSrc={optimizedImages[src]}
                            imageAlt={""}
                            onZoomStart={() => setIsZoomActive(true)}
                            onZoomEnd={() => setIsZoomActive(false)}
                            overlayOpacity={0}
                            overlayBoxOpacity={0}
                        />}
                        <Image className={useZoom ? "xs:block min-sm:hidden" : ''} src={src} alt={"image"} height={450} width={550} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </Carousel>
```